# Syntax error in Simple Javascript if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the following, which is supposed to write the value of `6` at the cookie `NotStarted` if the `Checkbox` `NotStarted` is checked and the value -1 if the Checkbox is unchecked

```
$("#NotStarted").change(function () 
{ $.cookie("NotStarted", if($("#NotStarted").is(':checked') == "true") {6} else {-1} , { expires: 20 * 365 }); return false; });
```

Well it is supposed to do so, since i have syntax errors...
What i am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

```
$("#NotStarted").change(function () {
    $.cookie("NotStarted", $("#NotStarted").is(':checked') ? 6 : -1, {
        expires: 20 * 365
    });
    return false;
});
```

looks like this can be simplified as(because you can use the checked property of the checkbox `NotStarted` )

```
$("#NotStarted").change(function () {
    $.cookie("NotStarted", this.checked ? 6 : -1, {
        expires: 20 * 365
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
if($("#NotStarted").is(':checked') == "true")
```

With

```
if($("#NotStarted").is(':checked'))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```
$("#NotStarted").change(function ()

    { $.cookie("NotStarted", $("#NotStarted").is(':checked') ? 6:-1 , { expires: 20 * 365 });

    return false; });
```